# Ant File, include another file

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ant, ear

Let me describe the scenario first. I have a main build file called main_build.xml. This file calls 4 other build files defined for sub projects, copies the Jars generated by sub project builds and then creates a WAR and finally EAR. 
I have my classpath dependencies defined in a XML file named my_clspath.xml. 
Now I have two questions: 
1. How do I include my_clspath.xml file within the main_build.xml? 
2. After including the my_clspath.xml in main_build, how do I make the classpath available for all 4 sub builds which are called from this main_build?.

my_clspath.xml content:

```
<fileset dir="../myApp_Ear/build/">
    <include name="**/*.jar" />
</fileset>

<fileset dir="../myApp_Ear/lib/">
    <include name="**/*.jar" />
</fileset>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<project name="Your Project">
    <include file="my_clspath.xml" />

    <ant antfile="sub1.xml" inheritAll="true" inheritRefs="true" />
</project>
```

Also, you should set an `id` on the Filesets. Just having them in your Ant file does not do anything.

```
<fileset dir="../myApp_Ear/build/" id="my.EAR.fileset">
    <include name="**/*.jar" />
</fileset>
```

Then, in `sub1.xml`, you can reference the filesets with `<fileset refid="my.EAR.fileset" />`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should really take a look at the [`<subant>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/subant.html) task. This does exactly what you're asking: You have a master `build.xml` file that's calling some sub-ant build files to build basic components.